# Probabilities on a dictionary of lists in python

Tags: python, dictionary, probability

I have this dictionary of lists:

```
my_dict = {'Summer':['Summer','Summer','gone'],'gone':['forever'],'forever':['gone']}
```

And I want the probabilities for each word in the list as a dictionary, in this case the expected dictionary is:

```
my_dict_probs = {'Summer':{'Summer':0.66,'gone':0.33}, 'gone':{'forever':1}, 'forever'{'Summer':1}
```

So I have tried this:

```
prob_dict = {}
for k,v in my_dict.items():
  prob_dict[k] = v/len(v)
prob_dict
```

And I get this error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'`. I guess that I should count per each unique value, so my approach is not working. Please, could you help me?

Comment: `prob_dict[k]` for `"Summer"`  is `['Summer','Summer','gone']`  - what do you thing should be done for `['Summer','Summer','gone'] / len(['Summer','Summer','gone'])` ? use `print()` to see what you get as values and refine your code.

Comment: Sure @PatrickArtner, my first thought was to try to get the count of unique values (converting into a set for example) per each element of the dictionary. But I got stuck into how to fit it into dict.items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
my_dict = {'Summer':['Summer','Summer','gone'],'gone':['forever'],'forever':['gone']}
for v in my_dict:
    my_dict[v]={j:round(my_dict[v].count(j)/len(my_dict[v]),2) for j in my_dict[v]}
print (my_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you @Sujay, your answer has the comprehension dictionary and round function I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Smallest change to your existing code:

```
my_dict = {'Summer':['Summer','Summer','gone'],'gone':['forever'],'forever':['gone']} 
    
prob_dict = {}
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    prob_dict[k] = {}                 # create inner dict
    for i in set(v):                  # for each element of the list, count it
        prob_dict[k][i] = v.count(i) / len(v)

print(prob_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Summer': {'Summer': 0.6666666666666666, 'gone': 0.3333333333333333}, 
 'gone': {'forever': 1.0}, 
 'forever': {'gone': 1.0}}
```

This is less effective then using `Counter` because it iterates the inner lists once for each unique value. `Counter` accomplishes the same in 1 pass no matter how long the inner list.

But it does not need any imports and modifies your existent code the least.

---

To get closer to what Counter does you could do

```
prob_dict = {}
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    prob_dict[k] = {}
    partial = 1.0 / len(v)
    for i in v:
        prob_dict[k].setdefault(i,0)
        prob_dict[k][i] += partial

print(prob_dict)
```

which now does only iterate the inner list once *BUT* now you incour floating values inaccuracies.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Counter` from itertools:

```
from collections import Counter

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    prob_dict[k] = {k1: v1 / len(v) for k1, v1 in Counter(v).items()}
```

```
>>> prob_dict
{'Summer': {'Summer': 0.6666666666666666, 'gone': 0.3333333333333333},
 'gone': {'forever': 1.0},
 'forever': {'gone': 1.0}}
```